# Using Microsoft Authentication Library MSAL with PnPjs

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, spfx

I've been reading the PnPjs page and I need to understand what it does:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/authentication/msaljsclient/#calling-sharepoint-via-msal
It seems like:

```
import { MsalClientSetup  } from "@pnp/msaljsclient";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

sp.setup({
    sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: MsalClientSetup({
            auth: {
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytentant.onmicrosoft.com/",
                clientId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                redirectUri: "https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/test.aspx",
            },
        }, ["https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/.default"]),
    },
});

const r = await sp.web();
```

Is providing a wrapper for a SharePoint app to be given perhaps an impersonation step, or for the app creator to allow other users to have elevated permissions? If not (oh I wish) then what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### you have to add baseUrl in the setup.

```
import { MsalClientSetup  } from "@pnp/msaljsclient";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

sp.setup({
    sp: {
        baseUrl: "https://{my tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/",
        fetchClientFactory: MsalClientSetup({
            auth: {
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytentant.onmicrosoft.com/",
            clientId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            redirectUri: "https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/test.aspx",
             },
         }, ["https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/.default"]),
     },
});

const r = await sp.web();
```

---

After adding baseUrl we can get SharePoint data and it's working with above code.

Comment: Does it give the SPFX webpart elevated permissions for any user who doesn't have Full Control?

Comment: @NightTom, yes you can allow elevated permissions with app permissions.

Comment: Would I need tenant admin to be able to use this?

Comment: @NightTom, If you have the client ID with required app permission & scope set then no need to be tenant admin, it works for normal user.

Comment: @NightTom, has this working for you to delegate the permission as per app permission. do let me know your issue got resolved or not?

Comment: haven't tried it yet, but if it does work then it would be a very useful thing. I've been told that SPFX doesn't allow permission changes from anyone without Full control, so again, if this works it will prove that wrong.

Comment: I've been told this is making the client side coding benefit redundant and makes it unsecure to use this. Any thoughts?